# C# unhandled error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, arrays

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Matrix_Algebra
{
    public struct S_Matrix_size
    {
        public int size_R, size_C;
        public S_Matrix_size(int r, int c)
        {
            this.size_R = r;
            this.size_C = c;
        }
    }

    public class C_Matrix_entries
    {
        private S_Matrix_size _size;
        private double[,] _entry;
        public C_Matrix_entries()
        {
            int r, c;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of rows and columns ");

            r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            _size = new S_Matrix_size(r, c);

            _entry = new double [_size.size_R,_size.size_C];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the entries from first row [left to right] to the last row ");
            for (int i = 0; i<_size.size_R; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the {0} row", i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j<_size.size_C;j++)
                {
                    _entry[i, j] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }       
        }
        public S_Matrix_size Size { get { return _size; } }             //property
        public double[,] Entry { get { return _entry; } }
    }
}

namespace Matrix_process_Algebra
{
    using Matrix_Algebra;
    public class STARTHERE
    {
        static void Main()                                                                                      // Main
        {
            C_Matrix_entries matrix = new C_Matrix_entries();
            if (matrix.Size.size_C == matrix.Size.size_R)
            {
                if (matrix.Size.size_C == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Determinant of the matrix? ");
                    Console.WriteLine("yes <y> or no <n> ?");
                    switch (Console.ReadLine())
                    {
                        case "n":
                        case "no":
                        case "N":
                        case "NO":
                        case "No":
                            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!!");
                            break;
                        case "yes":
                        case "y":
                        case "Y":
                        case "YES":
                            Console.WriteLine("The determinant of the entered matrix is  ");
                            Sqr_Determinant process_2x2 = new Sqr_Determinant();
                            double result = process_2x2.Sqr_Determinant_2x2(matrix.Entry);
                            Console.Write(result);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;

                    }
                }
                if (matrix.Size.size_C == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Determinant of the matrix? ");
                    Console.WriteLine("yes <y> or no <n> ?");
                    switch (Console.ReadLine())
                    {
                        case "n":
                        case "no":
                        case "N":
                        case "NO":
                        case "No":
                            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!!");
                            break;
                        case "yes":
                        case "y":
                        case "Y":
                        case "YES":
                            Console.WriteLine("The determinant of the entered matrix is  ");
                            Sqr_Determinant process_3x3 = new Sqr_Determinant();
                            double result = process_3x3.Sqr_Determinant_3x3(matrix.Entry);
                            Console.Write(result);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;

                    }
                }

                if (matrix.Size.size_C == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Determinant of the matrix? ");
                    Console.WriteLine("yes <y> or no <n> ?");
                    switch (Console.ReadLine())
                    {
                        case "n":
                        case "no":
                        case "N":
                        case "NO":
                        case "No":
                            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!!");
                            break;
                        case "yes":
                        case "y":
                        case "Y":
                        case "YES":
                            Console.WriteLine("The determinant of the entered matrix is  ");
                            Sqr_Determinant process_4x4 = new Sqr_Determinant();
                            double result = process_4x4.Sqr_Determinant_4x4(matrix.Entry);
                            Console.Write(result);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;

                    }
                }



            }
        }
    }
    public class Sqr_Determinant
    {
        public class C_sqr_Matrix_3x3                                                                //matrix 3x3
        {
            private double[,] _entries = new double[3, 3];
            public C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(double a,double b,double c,double d,double e,double f,double g,double h,double i)
            {
                this._entries[1, 1] = a;
                this._entries[1, 2] = b;
                this._entries[1, 3] = c;
                this._entries[2, 1] = d;
                this._entries[2, 2] = e;
                this._entries[2, 3] = f;
                this._entries[3, 1] = g;
                this._entries[3, 2] = h; 
                this._entries[3, 3] = i; 
            }
            public double[,] Entries { get { return _entries; } }
        }

        public class C_sqr_Matrix_2x2                                                               //matrix 2x2 
        {

            private double[,] _entries = new double[2,2];
            public C_sqr_Matrix_2x2(double a,double b, double c, double d)
            {
                this._entries[0, 0] = a;
                this._entries[0, 1] = b;
                this._entries[1, 0] = c;
                this._entries[1, 1] = d;
            }
            public double[,] Entries { get { return _entries; } }
        }

        public double Sqr_Determinant_2x2(double[,] entry)                                          //determinant 2x2
        {
            return entry[0, 0] * entry[1, 1] - entry[0, 1] * entry[1, 0];
        }

        public double Sqr_Determinant_3x3(double[,] entry)                                          //determinant 3x3
        {

            C_sqr_Matrix_2x2 _2233 = new C_sqr_Matrix_2x2(entry[1,1],entry[1,2],entry[2,1],entry[2,2]);
            C_sqr_Matrix_2x2 _1133 = new C_sqr_Matrix_2x2(entry[0,1],entry[0,2],entry[2,1],entry[2,2]);
            C_sqr_Matrix_2x2 _1122 = new C_sqr_Matrix_2x2(entry[0,1],entry[0,2],entry[1,1],entry[1,2]);

            return entry[0, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_2x2(_2233.Entries) - entry[1, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_2x2(_1133.Entries) + entry[2, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_2x2(_1122.Entries);
        }
        public double Sqr_Determinant_4x4(double[,] entry)
        {
            C_sqr_Matrix_3x3 _2244 = new C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(entry[1, 1], entry[1, 2], entry[1, 3], entry[2, 1], entry[2, 2], entry[2, 3], entry[3, 1], entry[3, 2], entry[3, 3]);
            C_sqr_Matrix_3x3 _1144 = new C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(entry[0, 1], entry[0, 2], entry[0, 3], entry[2, 1], entry[2, 2], entry[2, 3], entry[3, 1], entry[3, 2], entry[3, 3]);
            C_sqr_Matrix_3x3 _1144_ = new C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(entry[0, 1], entry[0, 2], entry[0, 3], entry[1, 1], entry[1, 2], entry[1, 3], entry[3, 1], entry[3, 2], entry[3, 3]);
            C_sqr_Matrix_3x3 _1133 = new C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(entry[0, 1], entry[0, 2], entry[0, 3], entry[1, 1], entry[1, 2], entry[1, 3], entry[2, 1], entry[2, 2], entry[2, 3]);
            return entry[0, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_3x3(_2244.Entries) - entry[1, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_3x3(_1144.Entries) +
                entry[2, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_3x3(_1144_.Entries) - entry[3, 0] * Sqr_Determinant_3x3(_1133.Entries);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug and find the error but I still cannot find where is the error.

Comment: Give us the full error message, including the line number. The error is simple. You used an array index that was less than zero, or larger than the size of your array. Find what line number it is on, and start debugging from there.

Comment: put a breakpoint and see exactly where it's breaking.

Comment: You might also want to read this [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor for `C_sqr_Matrix_3x3` is one of the issues. Arrays are zero-indexed. I also see other lines where you're treating this object as 1-indexed.

```
public C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(double a,double b,double c,double d,double e,double f,double g,double h,double i)
{
    this._entries[1, 1] = a;
    this._entries[1, 2] = b;
    this._entries[1, 3] = c;
    this._entries[2, 1] = d;
    this._entries[2, 2] = e;
    this._entries[2, 3] = f;
    this._entries[3, 1] = g;
    this._entries[3, 2] = h; 
    this._entries[3, 3] = i; 
}
```

should be

```
public C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(double a,double b,double c,double d,double e,double f,double g,double h,double i)
{
    this._entries[0, 0] = a;
    this._entries[0, 1] = b;
    this._entries[0, 2] = c;
    this._entries[1, 0] = d;
    this._entries[1, 1] = e;
    this._entries[1, 2] = f;
    this._entries[2, 0] = g;
    this._entries[2, 1] = h; 
    this._entries[2, 2] = i; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong here (see below). your array size is [3,3] means row: 0,1,2 column 0,1,2. There is no row:3 or column:3 and so the array out of index error.

```
public class sqr_Matrix_3x3                                                                
        {
            private double[,] _entries = new double[3, 3];
            public C_sqr_Matrix_3x3(double a,double b,double c,double d,double 
            e,double f,double g,double h,double i)
            {
                this._entries[1, 1] = a;
                this._entries[1, 2] = b;
                this._entries[1, 3] = c; <-- Error
                this._entries[2, 1] = d;
                this._entries[2, 2] = e;
                this._entries[2, 3] = f; <-- Error
                this._entries[3, 1] = g; <-- Error
                this._entries[3, 2] = h; <-- Error 
                this._entries[3, 3] = i; <-- Error 
            }
```